# How to reinstall win 10 update after going back to win 7

Tags: windows-7, reinstall

I have HP pavillion dv4 laptop carring genuine win7 sp1, i upgraded my win 10 update in august and unistalled it on next day for any reason and roll back to clean install of win 7. Now i again want to reinstall Windows 10 update in my laptop. though Get win 10 app is showing in tray and it's reporting that your free upgrade is on the way but I am failed to get the update since one and half months.
Pl help me to get win 10 update again on my laptop.

Answer (score 1):

Download the Microsoft Upgrade Tool to force the update.

It can be downloaded [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10).

After you have downloaded the tool, run it and select "I want to update this pc" to perform the update.

If the pc does not have internet, you can run this tool from another pc as well to create an USB stick that you can use to upgrade your other pc with.

Do note for the future: you do not have to roll back an install to windows 7 for a clean install. From windows 10 there are several methods to do a clean install. With this upgrade tool you can perform a clean install too, and if you have installed this version of windows 10 before on the pc, you can simply do a fresh install by booting from the USB stick. When it asks for a s/n, press skip. It will ask for it twice, but at the end of the installation, it will be activated, if you upgraded before.